# For which values of $ a $ can this function be a valid distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $ F(x) = a(x+1)^2(u(x+1)-u(x-1))+u(x+1) $  . For which values of $ a $ can this function be a valid distribution function?

I couldn't solve this question. Because for $x \geq 1 \implies F(x) = 1$ and for $ -1 < x < 1 $ i couldn't figure aout whether $F(x) = 1$ or not.